# Absolute value of negative zero - bug, or a part of the floating point standard?

Tags: haskell, floating-point

I know that signed zeros are used to distinguish underflow from positive or negative numbers, and so it's worth distinguishing them. Intuitively I feel that the absolute value of `-0.0` should be `0.0`. However, this is not what Haskell says:

```
Prelude> abs (-0.0)
-0.0
```

For what it's worth, Python 2.7 disagrees:

```
>>> -0.0
-0.0
>>> abs(-0.0)
0.0
```

Is this a bug, or a part of the standard?

Comment: Looks like the JVM acts like haskell in this respect, at least in frege the output is -0.0, too. Interestingly, (-0.0) == 0.0 is true.

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, C thinks the absolute value is 0 too, at least with gcc.

Comment: "so it's worth distinguishing them" – is it? I've always considered these extra values terribly hackish, they can usually be avoided (and IMO should be) by normalizing numbers at some suitable place in the calculation to prevent underflows.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There are very good reasons for -0.  Check this reference: William Kahan, "Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions, or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit"

Comment: relevant: prelude has a `isNegativeZero` function

Comment: @augustss Would you mind having a look at [this short gist](https://gist.github.com/2568426) and telling me what, if anything, is wrong with this alternative implementation of floating point in Haskell? I think it satisfies `abs x * signum x === x` (where `===` is representational equality, not `Eq` equality) and I can't see how it would break anything else.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I think that's a fine definition and it makes more sense than the one Haskell has now.  But I don't think it has big practical consequences.  The Haskell definition is there for historical reasons.  When Haskell was originally defined IEEE FP was not yet ubiquitous, so nobody thought that hard about negative zeroes.

Comment: @augustss Ah, I hadn't considered that there might be historical factors involved. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is definitely inconsistent with the IEEE 754 standard, which in its most recent incarnation says:

> abs(x) copies a floating-point operand x to a destination in the same
>   format, setting the sign bit to 0 (positive).

That's in section 5.5.1 of IEEE 754-2008, entitled 'Sign bit operations'.  Though I can't give a link to the standard itself, you can see roughly the same language in the last available [public draft](http://www.validlab.com/754R/drafts/archive/2006-10-04.pdf) of the standard, in section 7.5.1.  (In general the standard differs quite significantly from that draft, but this bit's almost unchanged.)

That doesn't make it a bug in Haskell unless Haskell specifically claims to follow the IEEE 754 standard, and moreover claims that the implementation of `abs` in the Prelude should map to the IEEE 754 `abs` function.  The standard merely requires that the `abs` operation must be provided, but says nothing about how it might be spelled.

Answer (score 7):

This is the behavior defined in the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1390006.4.4).

> **6.4.4 Magnitude and Sign**
>
> A number has a *magnitude* and a *sign*. The functions `abs` and `signum` apply to any number and satisfy the law:
>
> ```
> abs x * signum x == x
> ```
>
> For real numbers, these functions are defined by:
>
> ```
> abs x    | x >= 0  = x  
>          | x <  0  = -x  
>
> signum x | x >  0  = 1  
>          | x == 0  = 0  
>          | x <  0  = -1
> ```

Since negative zero is equal to zero, `-0.0 >= 0` is true, so `abs (-0.0) = -0.0`. This is also consistent with the definition of `signum`, since `-0.0 * 0.0 = -0.0`.

Comment: Fair enough. But the relation `abs x * signum x == x` would still hold if `abs (-0.0) == 0.0`, which seems more intuitive to me (and avoids the odd situation that `a == b` does not imply `f a == f b` when `a` and `b` are floating point values.

Comment: For example, I believe that the definition of `abs` could be changed so that the first line is `abs x | x > 0 = x` and a new line `| x == 0 = 0` is inserted, and nothing would break. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Wouldn't that just move the problem from `abs` to `signum`? Also, `a == b` does not imply `f a == f b` for many other functions either. For example, let `f x = 1 / x`. Then `f 0.0 == Infinity` while `f (-0.0) == -Infinity`.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. For example, consider the code at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/41384441e01df1f88706). Both `test 0.0` and `test (-0.0)` evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Also, ignore the part about `a == b => f a == f b` (for two reasons: 1. it's tangential to the discussion about `abs (-0.0)` and 2. I agree with you!)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: It depends on what notion of equality we're using. Letting both `abs (-0.0)` and `signum (-0.0)` return regular zero would satisfy the relation using `Eq` equality, but not in the stronger sense. I guess the root of the problem is that floating-point equality is somewhat misbehaved, and arguments have been made that floating point numbers shouldn't even be instances of `Eq` and `Ord` since things like `x == x` doesn't hold because `NaN /= NaN` and issues like this with negative zero.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I suppose to make this consistent you would need to have `signum (-0.0) == -0.0` and `signum 0.0 == 0.0`, which does complicate the matter somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

[As the IEEE standard says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Properties_and_handling), `0 == (-0)` even though they have different signs. It's quite reasonable, nothing is still nothing whatever sign you use. This means that

```
let nzero = (-0.0)
    a = abs nzero
in a == 0.0 && a == nzero
```

evaluates to `True`, because, in fact, it is the same whether `abs x == 0` or `abs x == (-0)`. Even though its a questionable choice, it does not seem to me like `abs (-0.0)
== (-0.0)` is a bug to me.

**Edit**:
As the comments point out, `show 0.0 /= show (-0.0)`. I'm not sure on how to justify this. The only thing that came to my mind at the moment is that, maybe, `Eq` does not represent a bounding contract with respect to referential transparency, e.g. two values does of a type do not really have to be represented in the same way to be considered equatable.

I'll write an update as soon as I can find some references about how `Eq` should be instantiated.

Comment: It is still unfortunate that his is so. For, one would think that the follwoing property should hold: `a == b ==> f a == f b`, but it doesnt if `f=show`

Comment: I agree that if you're just comparing floating points, then it doesn't make a difference. But it *can* make a measurable difference because, for example, `show 0.0 == show (-0.0)` evaluates to `False` even though `0.0 == (-0.0)` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Is the `Eq` typeclass bounded to be instantiated in such a way that `(==)` may be used for a formal definition of referential transparency? I mean, I could write an instance in such a way that `x == y` even though they don't have the same representation.

Comment: You certainly want the ability two consider two objects equal even though they have different representations, so `==` can't be used to reason about referential transparency *in general*. But it seems intuitive that the relation `a == b => f a == f b` should hold for numbers. This is just gut feeling though, and I don't have a rock-solid justification.

Comment: Also, I don't think this answer completely addresses the question (which isn't to say that it's not interesting and useful). I have no problem with the fact that `0.0 == (-0.0)`, in fact I think that should be the case. My issue is that `abs (-0.0) == -0.0`.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: I updated my answer. I agree with you, the fact that `a == b => f a == f b` doesn't hold for numbers is definitely counter-intuitive, but Haskell's implementation is compatible w.r.t. the IEE 754 standard, and as @hammar adds, the choice  for `abs (-0.0)` is consisntent with the law `abs x * signum x == x`.

Comment: As an example where you might expect `a == b` even though `a` and `b` were measurably different, consider lazy bytestrings. They are essentially a lazy list of strict chunks, but presented as if they are a single string, so we'd really like `fromChunks ["ab","c"] == fromChunks ["a","bc"]` even though `toChunks` will be able to tell them apart.

Comment: Also, disagree with your assertion that following the IEEE standard is "quite reasonable" :P

Comment: The `Eq` class doesn't really make any promises about being the same as semantic equality.  It's nice when it is, but it's something that can (and should) be broken is some cases.